# Method of moments estimators for binomial distribution

Tags: statistics

I'm not sure how to do part b of this question

Help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Presumably there might potentially be issues if observations were further apart or otherwise distributed differently from what  might be expected from a binomial distribution.

- What would your estimates be if $n=2$ and your observations were $4,10$?
- Or if your observations were $9,10$?

Are the values of $\tilde{k},\tilde{p}$ plausible?